# How can I increse the number of icons in word ribbon bar button group using office 365 manifest file

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-addins, office-js

I have been working on add number of icons as a group, to word ribbon bar using manifest in word add-in. But it show only 6 icons in the button group. Is that possible to add ribbon bar icons more than 6 to word ribbon bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Group is limited to 6 controls:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/group

If you need more, and personally I agree with you - six is limited, you need to drop a request at the program group.

Comment: Thank you for th reply. Could you please tell me is that possible to control the button group as we need? Because I have seen when we add icons to the button group, it will appear different ways. Sometimes it will appear horizontally direction large icons. sometimes vertically direction small icons.

Comment: It's better to ask 'new' questions in a new StackOverflow question to reach a wider audience. With regards to this, I think this is related to the size of your work environment. On smaller screens (or sized windows) the Ribbon scales to adapt to the available room.